# Stop jQuery from calling next events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, submit

I write a jQuery plugin the first time and I'm wondering if there is a way to stop jQuery from running the next attached events.

Example:

```
$(this).submit(function(){
    return $(this).do_some_validation();
}
```

If validation didn't pass (i.e. the function returned `false`), the form should not be submitted, but if there are any other event handlers attached, only last handler return value can prevent form from being submitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the stopPropagation() method:

```
$(this).submit(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    return $(this).do_some_validation();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You may also want to look at [event.stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), as stopPropagation "will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running" (for example, two submits handlers on the same form should still be triggered if using stopPropagation).

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function.

Answer (score 1):

`stopPropagation()` works on most events but may not always work on delegated events, `.live()` and `.delegate()`.

`return false;`  is a fool proof way if stopPropogation doesn't work **first**.

Answer (score 0):

I use this functions with `.live()` and never have problems

```
jQuery("a.entryTable, a.entryDelete").live("click", function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // code

    return false;
});
```